# iText version 7 - document.close() giving exception regarding PdfIndirectReference

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext7

I am using .Net > iText 7.

In pdf generation code -> after all operations are done and I say doc.Close(). This throws a pdfException with a message **"pdf.inderect.object.belong.to.other.pdf.document.Copy.object.to.current.pdf.document"**

After checking out the iText code, I found out that the exception in around *indirectReference* The internal property name is : *PdfException.PdfInderectObjectBelongToOtherPdfDocument*

**The stacktrace is :**

```
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutputStream.Write(PdfIndirectReference indirectReference)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutputStream.Write(PdfDictionary pdfDictionary)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutputStream.Write(PdfObject pdfObject)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutputStream.Write(PdfDictionary pdfDictionary)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutputStream.Write(PdfObject pdfObject)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutputStream.Write(PdfDictionary pdfDictionary)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfOutputStream.Write(PdfObject pdfObject)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter.WriteToBody(PdfObject pdfObj)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter.FlushObject(PdfObject pdfObject, Boolean canBeInObjStm)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.FlushObject(PdfObject pdfObject, Boolean canBeInObjStm)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfObject.Flush(Boolean canBeInObjStm)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage.Flush(Boolean flushXObjects)
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage.Flush()
   at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Close()
   at iText.Layout.Document.Close()
```

**Please note:** After starting the application, pdf gets generated for the very first time, but in all later tries I get this exception.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: Please show enough code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java i had the same issue because i used static constants for font. try not to use static values for PdfFont.
I removed this

```
private static PdfFont font;
```

And i replaced it with local values

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
```